# Разделить текст на div

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем добрый день!
Есть большой текст, со списками, картинками, мне нужно разделить на блоки div. Размер блоков динамический - зависит от разрешения монитора. Есть какие-нить готовые решения или в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Покажите текст и детальнее опишите проблему

Comment: Просто текст... куча текста, страниц на 10. Нужно загрузить весь текст(договора) сразу и листать его кнопками вперед-назад. Планировал разделить текст на div и динамически их листать

Comment: А каким именно должно быть деление?

Comment: Я думаю - определить сколько абзацев входит в блок. И заполнять их динамически. Вот только как определить сколько абзацев войдет в див?

Comment: Если только перед каждым абзацем есть какой-то символ

Comment: Так я жеж заранее не знаю текст.

Comment: А ещё раз, объясните задачу

Comment: Текст договора берется из базы. В нем есть теги img, p

Comment: И? {ещё 8 символов}

Comment: Есть блок на html странице, в который все данные однозначно не войдут. Есть пару кнопок - вперед-назад. Хочется, как-то удобочитаемо сделать листание страниц. Просто прокрутку вниз-вверх я понимаю как сделать.

Comment: Есть в CSS Columт свойство, что бы оно текст, который не вместился, переносило на другую колонку. А там, как сделать по-другом надо думать

Comment: Вроде то что нужно... только как получить доступ к n-ой колонке?

Comment: Если не решишь сам, я позже дам ответ